# How to make lodash debounce work with multiple dependencies of useCallback in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I am using lodash and useCallback to create a memorizable to have more understand how really callback work but stucking. Here is my simple example of my code

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { debounce } from "lodash";

const Test = ({ name }) => {
  const [testName, setTestName] = useState("");
  const changeName = () => {
    setTestName((Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7));
  };

  const debounceChangeTestName = useCallback(
    debounce(() => console.log(testName), 2000),
    // 1
    [testName]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    debounceChangeTestName(testName);
  }, [testName, debounceChangeTestName]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTestName(name);
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div>
      {testName} <br />
      <input type="button" onClick={changeName} value="Change" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test name="for test" />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Can someone please explain to me 2 questions

1. if i don't add dependency to debounce function (where i comment 1), why i can't log the value of testName? it's doesn't change in below useEffect?
2. if i add depencencies to debounce function, how can i log only the last result of testName(in this code above, it's log all of testName value until i stop clicking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you execute `useCallback`, the function gets remembered for as long as the dependencies are the same. If you hardcode a variable inside of the function, the executed function will always have the same result.
While using your `testMessage` in the dependency array does the trick, it does not really cause any debounce. Since the `debounce` is recreated every time the dependency changes, you always get a new instance that does not "remember" the previous call.

Just pass your `testName` as a parameter instead of relying on the value in state:

```
  const debounceChangeTestName = useCallback(
    debounce(msg => console.log(msg), 2000),
    [],
  )
```

Does that answer your questions?